# Is there any evidence that Alexander Davidson is actually dead?

Tags: comics, the-walking-dead

In the Alexandria community, Davidson is talked about about as some kind of boogeyman. The mere mention of his name is enough to make Douglas furious, and it is implied that the community was forced to kill Davidson. It is eventually discovered that Davidson was taking advantage of job assignment and manipulating women into sleeping with him, and was effectively responsible for the deaths of three people (one of whom killed themselves because of his actions).

The presence of a suspicious stranger in issue 93 (the beginning of "A Larger World") is making me wonder - is there any evidence that Davidson is actually dead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although he has a headstone in the Alexandria Safe Zone, he cannot be classified as dead. As Douglas Monroe said that he let Davidson out of the Safe Zone alive, and burnt the corpse of a zombie